# Stored Procedure with Column name in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have one table having three columns.I want to create stored procedure with three parameters as @Month,@Year and @column_Name to result output as below.I want to sum the values present in column1 and column2 i.e data which is present in HH:mm:ss format as string should result into minutes [Eg. '01:00:00' results as 60]with parameters in where clause.

Note : `Column1` and `Column2` have datatype `varchar` with data as `hh:mm:ss` format.

Sample Date in Table

```
Date_Col                     Column1        Column2

2014-12-17 10:00:00.000      01:10:00       00:15:00
2014-12-18 11:12:00.000      02:22:00       00:52:00
2015-01-15 09:32:00.000      00:34:00       01:09:00
2015-01-16 11:43:00.000      10:00:00       02:00:00
```

Result of stored procedure

```
@Month = 12 ,@Year = 2014,@Column_Name = Column1
```

then

```
Date_Col                             Column1
--------------------------------------------------------------------    
2014-12-17                           70   [01:10:00 = 60 + 10 min]
2014-12-18                           142
```

Below is the SP which i am referring

```css
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test_SP] 
@Column_Name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        CAST(CONVERT(DATE, date_col) AS Varchar(50)) AS 'Date',
        DATEPART(HOUR, CAST(@Column_Name AS varchar(50))) * 60 +
            DATEPART(mi, CAST (CAST(@Column_Name AS varchar(50)) AS varchar)) as Column_Name
    FROM 
        Test_Table 
    WHERE
        @Column_Name IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
                         FROM [TEST].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                         WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Test_Table') 
END
```

But it returns an error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test_SP, Line 8
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Please Help

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If you have dates - **store them** in an appropriate datatype - `DATE` or `DATETIME2(3)` or something - but **do not** store them as `VARCHAR` ! You're just asking for trouble....

Comment: Ok and what about passing parameter in select query sir

Comment: convert(date,date_col) as  'Date' is this f9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NOT mess with string functions to get the time parts. That's about the worst way possible to do this. Instead, let Sql Server convert it to a [`Time`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) type and use Date and Time functions. Both SELECTs in this code produced `70` for me:

```
declare @test varchar(8); set @test = '01:10:00'

declare @t1 time;set @t1 = CAST(@test as time);
declare @t2 time;set @t2 = '00:00:00';

select DATEDIFF(minute, @t2, @t1)
select DATEPART(hour, @t1) * 60 + DATEPART(minute, @t1)
```

There's an implicit cast in there that converts the @test value to a compatible type for the `DATEPART()` function. This will do **much** better at getting your minute values, and things will go better still if you store the data using the `TIME` type in the first place.

For the column name part, you should use a CASE statement for this. Full code will look like this:

```
SELECT Date_Col, 
    DATEDIFF(minute, '00:00:00',
       CASE @ColumnName WHEN 'Column1' THEN Column1
                        WHEN 'Column2' THEN Column2
                        ELSE NULL END) As Minutes
FROM Test_Table
WHERE YEAR(Date_Col) = @Year AND MONT(Date_Col) = @Month
```

Comment: and where to pass the parameter sir means in where clause

Comment: Updated to include Year/Month parameters. You don't need the the column in the where clause with this answer; you'll still get the right results.

Comment: it is not resulting anything i have declared parameter ColumnName,Month and year as varchar(50),INT,INT

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test_SP3, Line 7
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. for Column2

Comment: Thanksssssssssss a lot JOEL